# Can't make exercise from Jason Hickey's "Introduction to Objective Caml" book

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> Suppose you have a function on integers f : int -> int that is mono-
>   tonically increasing over some range of arguments from 0 up to n. That is,
>   f i < f (i + 1) for any 0 ≤ i < n. In addition f 0 < 0 and f n > 0. Write a
>   function search f n that finds the smallest argument i where f i ≥ 0.

Now i wrote this

```
let search f n =
    let min = f 0 in
let rec searchin i =
    if i >= n then min
        else
            if f min > f i then min = i
            searchin i+1;;
```

But it crashes with error:

> Error: Parse error: "in" expected after [binding] (in [expr])

What wrong?
And my implementation is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let search f n =
    let min = f 0 in
    let rec searchin i =
        if i >= n then min
        else
        if f min > f i then min = i;
        searchin i+1 in searchin 0;;
```

you forgot to call the function.

Anyway it is false, the correct search is

```
let search f n =
  let rec searchin i =
    if i>=n then failwith("error that is not possible")
    else if f i >0 then i-1 else searchin (i+1)
  in
  searchin 0;;
```

you can also search with a loop

```
let search f n =
    let i = ref 0 in
    while f (!i) < 0 do
        i:= !i +1;
    done;
!i;;
```

Comment: you make statement of serch without n argument. You think it's correct?

Comment: yeah, your function is working.
Sorry, maybe i don't understand at all, but how function f look like?
I write this 
    (fun i -> if (i >= 2) && (i < 5) then i+1 else i)

Comment: That function isn't monotonically increasing near 0. Also it doesn't fulfill the requirement that `f 0 < 0`.

Comment: you can take the function fun x -> 3*x -1 for example

Answer (score 1):

why not use binary search:

```
let rec binarysearch begin end func = 
if begin=end 
then begin 
else 
  let m=(begin+end)/2 in 
    if (func m)<0 
    then binarysearch (m+1) end func 
    else binarysearch begin m func;;
```

Answer (score -1):

The function by nlucaroni is not working. The correct solution is as follows

```
let search f n =
     let rec aux i =
     if i>n then 
        failwith("error that is not possible")
     else 
        (if f i >=0 then 
            i
        else
            aux (i+1))
in aux 0;;
```